# Modeling change over time when response variable has different range and variance?

Tags: panel-data, bias, generalized-estimating-equations

Some background:
I am working with data from a large cohort study. My outcome is a measure of fine motor skills, and was adapted from a psychometrically validated instrument (the short version included in this study was also validated). Because the outcome is measured at 18 and 36 months, the skills being evaluated are different (e.g., turning pages of a book at 18 months versus mature pencil grip at 36 months).

I am more concerned, however, that the number of items differs between time points: three items were asked at 18 months and 2 were asked at 36 months. I had been modeling the outcome at a single time point as following a Poisson distribution (count of "delays"). When looking at a difference in change over time between several exposure groups (data in multiple rows per subject, model includes time, group, and interaction), I of course see a strong in delays over time, because the opportunity to report a delay is less at 36 months.

So, my questions:
Should I be concerned about the interaction effect? 
If I see a significant group-by-time interaction, is it reasonable to attribute this to a difference in change between exposure groups, or am I introducing bias? 
If this is not a valid approach, does anyone have a suggestion (preferably in the form of reference materials!) for alternative analytic approaches?